# Media cannot be converted to javafx.scene.media.Media

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

```
class SongPlayer{

   static void playMP3(String fileName) {
      new javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel();
      String uriString = new File(fileName).toURI().toString();
      Media m = new Media(uriString);
      MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
      mp.play();
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
     playMP3("Batman.wav");
   }
}
```

I am getting  `Media cannot be converted to javafx.scene.media.Media` error at

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(m);
```

I don't what is the issue. I checked the documentation but `MediaPlayer` takes `Media` object as argument.

Comment: What's the fully qualified class name of the `Media` class you use?

Comment: i used `import javafx.scene.media.Media;` and it worked thanks.